# Is a hydrocarbon bio-battery feasible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, fuel, enzymes

Hydrocarbons have some of the highest energy densities and specific energies of any chemical fuel.  Unfortunately, our primary use of them is in thermal engines, whose efficiency is limited by Carnot's Theorem.  Batteries, on the other hand, do not have this limitation and can be engineered to arbitrary efficiency.

Sony has designed a [biobattery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biobattery) which runs on [glucose](https://www.sony.com/en/SonyInfo/News/Press/200708/07-074E/).  While this is an impressive achievement, liquid [propane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#In_chemical_reactions_(oxidation)) and butane have a much higher specific energy (> 3x) than glucose, as well as a higher energy density (not surprising, since glucose contains oxygen atoms which are basically dead weight for a battery).

Is there any reason that the enzyme catalyst approach could not be applied to simple short-chain hydrocarbons like propane through octane?  I assume that the battery's performance (current discharge) is proportional to the amount of enzyme present, and thus, the weight overhead for the battery depends on the amount of desired current.  Are the enzymes expected to be a significant fraction of the mass/volume of the battery?

It seems that an electric airliner running on Jet-A fed to bio-batteries could theoretically have more than twice the range of best current turbofans.  Is this an unreasonable conclusion?

Comment: There are millions of people thinking like you. But nobody has found a way of having an alcane react to produce electrons in a cell, as it theoretically should. Oxygenated derivates of alcanes are able to produce electricity, but not alcanes. Maybe somebody will find a trick or a catalyzer in the future. Who knows ?

Comment: They were called, at least the highest terms, paraffins, from parum  affinis, scarce reactivity.

Comment: Hydrocarbons could be used in a fuel cell at high temperature. Alkanes can be cracked with heat (and catalyst, to make the process faster and more efficient), yielding hydrogen suitable for use in the cell, and a residue containing more carbon. In a similar way, ammonia can be used in fuel cells (though NH3 is far more reactive than CnH2n+2).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I suppose fuel cells are the general form of "turn combustion into a battery"... it boils down to finding the right catalysts and electrolytes, then?

Comment: Worth noting that typical bio battery designs do not even capture all of the energy in glucose. They only convert to gluconolactone not CO2. Just doing that would greatly increase energy yield before you even consider a switch to alkane